# Solving the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^x e^{-e^x} e^{-x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am struggling to solve the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^x e^{-e^x} e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$

Is there a way to find an exact solution in terms of standard mathematical functions (including non-elementary functions such as the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function))?

---

**What I have tried:**

Through substitution ($u = e^x$) I have found that the value is equal to

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u} e^{-(ln\ u)^2}\,du$$

I have tried further substitutions but none have helped me arrive at a value.

I know from WolframAlpha that the value is around $0.529$.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form.  Note that $e^{-(\ln u)^2}=u^{-u}$

Comment: this is an approxomatively value $$4.45154339423883477590131278024006069613733444874806465064361880223031\
4051283525747906768214564914864$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner WolframAlpha tells me that it is closer to $0.529$.

Comment: the inverse symbolic calculator and wolfram led to nothing, so i doubt there's a closed form. Where did this problem come from? Any application or broader context?

Comment: @Dando18 It is a simplified version of an expression involving Poisson distribution and normal distribution.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Oh well, thanks for the assessment. I think you mean $u^{-ln\ u}$ btw.

Comment: Oh whoops, yes, that is what I meant to say.

Comment: Even the most superficial research would have shown that the existence of a closed solution is very unlikely. To reward the absence of any such research (to call that half-hearted substitution "struggle" is a common joke at this site) with upvotes is perverse.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you for your comment. How can one tell that a solution is very unlikely? It may be obvious to you, but it's far from obvious to me. Please note that I did not call my substitution a "struggle" and that I did more research (which unfortunately led me nowhere of interest).

Comment: Knowing about normal distribution, you know that $e^{-x^2}$ doesn't have an elementary integral, but you think $e^{x-e^x-x^2}$ might have?!

Comment: @ProfessorVector The integral of $e^{-x^2}$ has a solution in terms of the error function. I have edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: By approximating $e^{-\log^2(u)}$ with $u e^{1-u}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ (that is not so bad) we get that the wanted integral is not too far from $\frac{e}{4}$, but about a closed form... good luck.

Comment: Would it be worth it to try computing the integral using residues?

Comment: @AlexBates I was also thinking that way, but since the function is (I think) holomorphic it has 0 residues to contribute to a calculation using a closed loop. Then we are left again with the real line segment and we're basically back to square one. But you might have other ideas...

Comment: if you would have some tunable parameter, one could do nice asymptotics with this kind of integral